# sigaction: restore handler or not?

Tags: c, unix, signals

if i call sigaction at the beginning of my code,

```
sigaction(SIGPIPE, &pipe_act, NULL);
```

if i receive sigpipe, after the execution of pipe_act the handler installed remains pipe_Act, or the default handler is automatically set for sigpipe?

Comment: Do you actually need `sigaction`, or would the simpler `signal` suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether or not your flags (`pipe_act->sa_flags`) include `SA_RESETHAND`. If yes, then the signal handler is a "one-shot" and gets removed after having been called (i.e. the handler is reset to the default handler), but if not, then the handler remains in place until you change it manually.

Comment: i didn't know SA_RESETHAND (until now). i don't modify in any way that flag. So it remains pipe_act ?

Comment: @giozh: Correct, the flag is not set by default.